# How to auto populate stream fields in views in pyrocms?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I am using pyrocms community edition. I am having a trouble for auto populating the stream fields in the view page. I am trying to edit the field and the old value does not populate by itself. 
I am well aware that auto populate feature can be achieved through CI Form builder.

This is how I have set up my form

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>
        <?php foreach($profile_fields as $field): ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo $field['input'] ?> // This will generate input field but
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My plan B would be to generate form with code-igniter form builder if the solution does not comes. But since I am doing in a Pyrocms 'stream-way', if stream field has an option to auto populate, it would be great.

Comment: which model/library/function did you use to get $profile_fields?

Comment: it was obtained by stream fieds driver function: $profile_fields =  $this->streams->fields->get_stream_fields()

Comment: and did you provide the data through the $current_data or $entry_id parameters? Check the function definition and comments in system/cms/libraries/Streams/drivers/Streams_fields.php on line 343